# Why JVM does not allow to throw Unchecked Exception from static block?

Tags: java, exception, static, unchecked-exception

Why JVM does not allow to throw **Unchecked Exception** from static block?
But it still allows them implicitly (e.g: calling method on null object).

Note: The question is more academic and not from real life issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw it with a little hack but you will get [ExceptionInInitializerError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html):

> Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An **ExceptionInInitializerError** is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

```
static {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored){}
}
```

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   ...